# A few basic questions in logic from Zorich's mathematical analysis

Tags: logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be two mathematical statements, each of which can either be true, or false. The first problem is to show that:

> If $A$ is false, then $A \implies B$ is always true $\cdots\cdots(\star)$

Now I can consider $A:\{x>0\}$ and $B:\{x>5\}$. Now suppose we observe that $x=-2$. Then $A$ is false. But we never have $A \implies B$. Is the problem wrongly stated or am I missing something?

Two problems in the same line are to show that:

$(i)~~(A \implies B)\implies (not~~A)~~or~~B$

$(ii)~~not~~(A \implies B)\implies A~~and~~(not~~B)$

I can solve these two if I can show $(\star)$. I can sense that there is some *vacuously true* argument coming up but the counter example (?) is bugging me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The fact that "$A \Rightarrow B$" is true when $A$ is false is part of the definition of "$\Rightarrow$". You also seem to be mixing things up when you bring in events and observations.

Comment: By definition ($A$ is true) and ($A \implies B$) implies that $B$ is true. Since one of the  conditions is violated ($A$ is false), we have $B$ is false. What can I say about ($A \implies B$)?

Comment: When $A$ is false, the statement "$A\Rightarrow B$" is true, *by definition*. That does not say anything about $B$. Thus "$A\Rightarrow B$" is equivalent to "not($A$) or $B$".

Comment: Use a truth table, essentially the definition of the material implication $A\to B$  is by definition TRUE, unless ( $A$ is true, and $B$ is false.)

Comment: Another way this can be said, is $A\to B$ is true, whenever A is false, or whenever B is true.

Comment: @amWhy: That helps. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, aditi_ray!

Comment: Have you learned the truth-tables for, say, $\lnot a,\; a\to b, \; a\lor b, \; a\land b,\;?$

Comment: Note that for $(i)$, it's true that $A\to B \iff  \lnot A \lor B$.  Check the truth table for the left-hand side, and the right-had side of $\iff$. $\;(ii):\; \lnot(A\to B) \iff \lnot (\lnot A \lor B)$ (from (i)), $\;\equiv A \land \lnot B.$  Again, to convince yourself, compare the truth-table for $ \lnot(A\to B)$ with the truth-table for $A \land  \lnot  B$.

Comment: aditi_ray: Let me know if you'd like me to post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the problem is that you are *parameterizing* your propositions, which is a bit premature [this is only *propositional calculus* - later comes *predicate calculus*].  What I mean is: When you write 'A : {x > 0}' you are (I assume) asserting that A is the property 'x > 0'.  In other words, you are parameterizing A - what you really want to write is A(x).  But this is *neither true nor false* until you specify exactly what x is [similarly for B(x)].  So let us take a few examples:

x = -2 : Then A(-2) is the property '-2 > 0' and B(-2) is the property '-2 > 5'.  Neither of these is true.  So 'A(-2) ==> B(-2)' is *vacuously* true.

x = 2 : Then A(2) is '2 > 0' [true] and B(2) is '2 > 5' [false]  Hence 'A(2) ==> B(2)' is false.

x = 6 : Then A(6) is '6 > 0' [true] and B(6) is '6 > 5' [true]  Hence 'A(6) ==> B(6)' is true.

*[I assume the cases like 'x=2' leads to your assertion 'we never have A==>B' but the cases like 'x=6' argue against that assertion]*

To reiterate: When you try to define a property as a relation involving an unknown, you *are not defining a proposition*.  For the definition to be a proposition [i.e to have a definite truth-value], it must be completely defined.

Comment: Okay. I understand the hole in my example. In your example, when $x=-2$, we have both $A(-2)$ and $B(-2)$ to be true. Then why is $A(-2) \implies B(-2)$ vacuously true? I've some confusion on this *vacuously true* thing.

Comment: Why could not we say that $A(-2)$ is false $\implies$ $B(-2)$ is false. And hence the contrapositive $B(-2) \implies A(-2)$, and not necessarily the other way around.